# Why cache-control HTTP header for requests?

Tags: http, httpclient, cache-control, httpserver, http-caching

I recently went through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) article. It says that not only response, the requests can also include `cache-control` options.

Though I understood, it can be utilized by server responses meaningfully, I don't clearly understand why they are needed in requests. Unfortunately I could find nothing on internet which got answers to my problem.

Any one has an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 cache and the associated headers that control cache behavior are defined in the [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234). Caching is an entirely optional feature of HTTP though.

---

The [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) header is used to specify **directives** for caches along the request/response chain. Such cache directives are
unidirectional in that the presence of a directive in a request does not imply that the same directive is to be given in the response.

> Cache directives are identified by a token, to be compared
> case-insensitively, and have an optional argument, that can use both
> token and quoted-string syntax.  For the directives defined below
> that define arguments, recipients ought to accept both forms, even if
> one is documented to be preferred.  For any directive not defined by
> this specification, a recipient MUST accept both forms.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control   = 1#cache-directive
>
> cache-directive = token [ "=" ( token / quoted-string ) ]
> ```

Find below the [directives](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1) that can be used in the request for the [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) header:

> [**5.2.1.1.  max-age**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.1)
>
> [...] The `max-age` request directive indicates that the client is
> unwilling to accept a response whose age is greater than the
> specified number of seconds. [...]
>
> This directive uses the token form of the argument syntax: e.g.,
> `max-age=5` not `max-age="5"`. [...]

> [**5.2.1.2.  max-stale**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.2)
>
> [...] The `max-stale` request directive indicates that the client is
> willing to accept a response that has exceeded its freshness
> lifetime. [...]
>
> This directive uses the token form of the argument syntax: e.g.,
> `max-stale=10` not `max-stale="10"`. [...]

> [**5.2.1.3.  min-fresh**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.3)
>
> [...] The `min-fresh` request directive indicates that the client is
> willing to accept a response whose freshness lifetime is no less than
> its current age plus the specified time in seconds. [...]
>
> This directive uses the token form of the argument syntax: e.g.,
> `min-fresh=20` not `min-fresh="20"`. [...]

> [**5.2.1.4.  no-cache**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.4)
>
> The `no-cache` request directive indicates that a cache MUST NOT use
> a stored response to satisfy the request without successful
> validation on the origin server.

> [**5.2.1.5.  no-store**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.5)
>
> The `no-store` request directive indicates that a cache MUST NOT
> store any part of either this request or any response to it. [...]

> [**5.2.1.6.  no-transform**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.6)
>
> The `no-transform` request directive indicates that an intermediary
> (whether or not it implements a cache) MUST NOT transform the
> payload [...].

> [**5.2.1.7.  only-if-cached**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.7)
>
> The `only-if-cached` request directive indicates that the client only
> wishes to obtain a stored response. [...]

In a similar way, [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) also defines the [directives](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2) that can be used in the response for the [`Cache-Control`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) header.

Comment: your answer quite caters what I expected. As a side question, may I know, have you frequently used those for requests? Or is it quite rare cases?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Caching is an entirely optional feature of HTTP. So you are not required to implement it. Honestly, I never used such directives for requests, but it doesn't mean that I will never use them :)

Comment: request cache control header / directives is what the browser uses when you disable cache in dev tools