# If a Cache-Control directive is present on request and response header, which takes precedence?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

I ready the [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) Cache-Control documentation. But it's not clear for me what would be the behavior of a resource where the request header set max-age to 0 but the response header have the max-age=3600.

> - Modifications of the basic expiration mechanism; these may be imposed by either the origin server or the user agent.

But which one would take effect?

> - Controls over cache revalidation and reload; these may only be
>   imposed by a user agent.

Is max-age this kind of control? If yes, the request header would take effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why cache-control HTTP header for requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507679/why-cache-control-http-header-for-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the header may have the same name, the role of `Cache-Control` in the request and response is different. Both are used by a cache, when it is either deciding whether a request needs to be sent to the [origin server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.1), or whether it can [store the response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#page-6) for future use.

> what would be the behavior of a resource where the request header set max-age to 0 but the response header have the max-age=3600

A request with `max-age=0` indicates that a client requires a new response. The cache would forward the request to the origin server.

A *response* header of `max-age=3600` would be stored along with the response in any caches, and returned to the client. It would be compared against any *future* requests to determine whether this response is [still fresh enough](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#page-11) for that client.

Comment: What if request set `Cache-Control` to `no-cache` while server set it to `no-store`? Aren't they effectively conflicting? What will cache do in this case?