# Cache-Control: What happens if Browser and Client specifies a Cache-Control header?

Tags: http, nginx, caching, browser, cache-control

I am struggling with Cache Control in my application.

Apparently my browser was requesting the HTML files with Max-Age=0. My web-server doesn't have a directive, but the CDN proxy was passing a cache directive with 24 hours time to live.

The question is, what happens if a browser pass No-Cache in the request, for example, but the server specifies a Cache time? What has the highest precedence?

Can I ignore cache completely from client, or am I always subject to what the server responds?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a Cache-Control directive is present on request and response header, which takes precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818838/if-a-cache-control-directive-is-present-on-request-and-response-header-which-ta)

Comment: @Joe it does, partially. What about the browser passing a no cache, but receiving an indication to cache (or time to live) in the response. The behavior is to cache or not to cache the artifacts?

Comment: Also answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023690/which-cache-control-header-values-are-used-to-be-used-by-client-server

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the meaning of header in a request and in a response.

In a request header, MaxAge=0 means "I want the freshest version of this content from the origin server". A client should be able to specify a non-zero value and any proxy cache with a version older than that, even if it is still considered valid, *should* make a new request upstream, although the HTTP/1.1 spec is a little vague on this one.

In a response header, Max-Age=N means "here is the content and you can re-use for up to N seconds (less any specified value for the current Age) without asking for it again".

There is no conflict. A client is quite entitled to ask again before the cache time has expired.

There is a complication here if your origin server is not specifying a Max-Age (and not specifying an Expires header). It shouldn't do that (unless it has been explicitly told to do so). That suggests that the proxy is not behaving nicely and you should be talking to the proxy service provider.

Given that the proxy is not behaving nicely it may be serving up stale content even if the client is asking for a fresh copy.

However it's not all their fault. If you do not want the content to be cachable then you should be explicitly stating that in your response headers with `Cache-control: no-cache`. In the absence of explicitly caching directive a client and an intermediate cache *may* reuse content.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what if the client (browser) pass a no-cache and the server sends a Expires or a Max age? Does the client still cache it? In your answer you say to add a no-cache in the response. talking more specifically about browsers, an not about the the HTTP standard in general, if a browser passes no-cache, it will never cache things, no matter the response headers?

Comment: I worry to not be clear in this question. From your answer i got that: 1- Max Age in the request is enough to ask the servers for new content (if exists). 2- Max-Age in the response tells the browser the amount of time it is safe to still use that version. Question 1: will browsers use this file served with max age or request again in the next reload? Because the requests are always the same: max-age=0, although the response says "keep it for N secs". Maybe it is vague and depends on the implementation?! Question 2: what if Browser requests No-cache and server responds "keep it for N secs"?

Comment: I suspect we are talking about an (A|S)JAX request where the code is explicitly setting the header at the client as I've never seen browsers do this natively. And you seem to be trying to solve the XY problem - if you don't want any caches to replay cached content then this should be set in the headers on the origin.